# MySQL - Why such different performance with timestamps in these 2 queries?

Tags: mysql, performance

I wrote a Perl script that it makes some SQL queries in a table with more than 140000 rows and expanding.

I want to compare dates and get some rows, but I realized that just by changing one SQL query, I get so much different execution speeds.

Take a look at the following test results performing 100 $sql queries.
The only line I change in the script between different executions is the $sql line.

I ran the tests many times and I always get similar results, so I guess that it is not related to caching issues.

```
my $sql = "SELECT `mem_used`, `swap_used`, `mem_total` 
FROM `$config{db}{data_table}` 
WHERE  `host_id` = $host_id 
AND date >= '$date' 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , `date`, '$date' ) <= $interval;"; # VERY SLOW

time ./data_smoothing.pl

real    1m28.818s
user    1m6.516s
sys     0m0.256s
```

---

```
my $sql = "SELECT `mem_used`, `swap_used`, `mem_total` 
FROM `$config{db}{data_table}` 
WHERE  `host_id` = $host_id 
AND date >= '$date' 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date')) <= ($interval * 60);"; #SLOW

$ time ./data_smoothing.pl

real    0m10.005s
user    0m0.108s
sys     0m0.028s
```

---

```
my $sql = "SELECT `mem_used`, `swap_used`, `mem_total` 
FROM `$config{db}{data_table}` 
WHERE  `host_id` = $host_id 
AND (`date` BETWEEN '$date' 
AND DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL $interval MINUTE));"; #FAST

$ time ./data_smoothing.pl

real    0m0.190s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.016s
```

---

How the table is created (taken from a mysqldump)

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `mem_total` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mem_used` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `swap_total` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `swap_used` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CPU_count` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `load_avg_1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `load_avg_5` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `load_avg_15` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `uptime` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpuIdlingTime` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rxBytesTotal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txBytesTotal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rxPacketsTotal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txPacketsTotal` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`host_id`),
  KEY `fk_data_hosts` (`host_id`),
  KEY `date_memtot_hosts` (`date`,`mem_total`,`host_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_data_hosts` FOREIGN KEY (`host_id`) REFERENCES `hosts` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=145300 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last one is fastest because your comparison lends itself well to indexing.  The others, not so much.

See, when you call a function (or do just about anything else) with your column's value before you test it, you make it nearly impossible to use an index to quickly find matching rows.  The engine has to basically go through the whole table, grabbing a date, doing some math with it, and *then* checking whether the condition is true.

Meanwhile, if you just say `BETWEEN this_value AND that_value`, MySQL doesn't have to do much at all -- it can consult the index and just find the two endpoints of the range, which is much faster.

The call to `DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL $interval MINUTE)` doesn't have much effect on the run time, cause MySQL is generally smart enough to cache values it knows won't change so it doesn't have to calculate them again each time.

As for the reason for the difference between the first two, i couldn't tell you.  Perhaps `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is just that slow.  Perhaps the conversion and math are much simpler with timestamps, particularly considering `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date')` doesn't need recalculating each time.  But all that's really just guessing.

Comment: V, always try an EXPLAIN to help ans this type of Q.  In this case, the query engine can use `date_memtot_hosts` for a between on `date` so doesn't have to do a full table scan as in (1) or a part table scan as in (2).  If this is a *hot* query then try 3 plus adding an additional key on (host_id, date) on the table.  This will go like shit off a shovel.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an Indexing related issue, can you post the table create statement so we can see your indexes?

I know < or > aren't good for using indexes, while BETWEEN is fine... probably getting benifit of first date listed in the BETWEEN clause.  Anything in DATE_ADD is not going to be used for indexing purposes (since functions break indexes)

Comment: Just added the extra info as asked

Comment: I stick to the fact inequalities are not optimal when picking indexes, while BETWEEN does benefit.

Answer (score 0):

For the TIMESTAMPDIFF version, the order of arguments seems to be wrong. In order to obtain a positive result, the 2nd argument should be the later of the two dates. The way it is written, TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , `date`, '$date' ) <= $interval would always be true. Since more result rows would be returned that may explain why the performance of the TIMESTAMPDIFF version seems to be so much worse than the UNIX_TIMESTAMP version.